# Longman telegram bot clone message

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a command replying a message. When you write
/share replying a message the bot have to clone the message and send in to me in pvt.
My problem is that I want to manage all type of messages [ also photos, documents, contact and not just text ]

There is someone who wrote a "cloneMessage" function ?! I'm using